# Best way to implement image enlargement on Thumbnails on Product Pages in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

1. List item

My product thumbnails don't enlarge on click using gatsby-remark-images-medium-zoom@1.2.1 or gatsby-remark-images-zoom

Followed readme on both and declared plugins in gatsby-config, also tried experimenting with option configurations. To see what I mean here's an example: https://store.shaka-surf.com/products/eco-medium-g5-surf-fins

```
   import React from 'react'
   import Img from 'gatsby-image'
   import { graphql, useStaticQuery } from 'gatsby'

   export default function Thumbnails({ src }) { 
   const { allMoltinProduct } = useStaticQuery(graphql`
     query allMoltinProductsQuery {
     allMoltinProduct {
       nodes {
         id
         images {
           childImageSharp {
            sizes(sizes: "max-width: 801px) 100vw, 801px") {
              srcSet
              sizes
       }
      } 
    }
   }
 }
 }
`)

 return (
   <div className="thumbnail-container">
     {allMoltinProduct.nodes.map(product => (
      <React.Fragment key={product.id}>
        {product.images.map((image, index) => (
          <ul className="thumbnail-list">
          <li key={`image-${index}`} style={{display: 'inline-block', float: 
 'none', color: '#F2F4F5', width: '44px', height: '44px'}}>
          <Img fluid={image.childImageSharp.fluid.src} 
          />
          <img sizes={image.childImageSharp.sizes.sizes} src= 
 {image.childImageSharp.fluid.src}  srcSet= 
 {image.childImageSharp.sizes.srcSet} className="thumbnail-image medium-zoom- image" loading="lazy" alt={product.name} />
          >
          </li>
          </ul>
        ))}
      </React.Fragment>
      ))} 
  </div>
 )
 }
```

Would like the product thumbnails to enlarge.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: managed to get Lightbox from this [repo](https://github.com/416serg/gatsby-starter-lightbox/tree/master/src/components) working on my gallery which is good enough for now. Will come back to the thumbnails at a later date.